# How to distinguish between create and update in process builder?

Tags: process-builder

I wanted to add two criteria one for only record creation and second for only record update in Process builder.

Comment: did you look at `ISNEW()`?

Comment: Thanks, It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce provides a convenient Formula expression to test if a record is being inserted versus updated - [ISNEW()](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5)

Created

```
ISNEW()
```

Updated

```
NOT(ISNEW())
```